# Cannot find UPI apps on emulator's play store

Tags: android-emulator, google-pay, paytm, upi

I am trying to test my payment integration on the android emulator. But on the play store I cannot find any of the UPI apps like Google pay or PayTM or Phone pe or even BHIM.

I am using Android 7.0 with google play support

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to test the UPI intent on the android emulator because the phone on which UPI intent is to be run should be binded with a phone number. Try testing on a device and you would get all UPI supported apps.

Comment: 1. But I should at least be able to download the app from play store onto my emulator? 2. Is there no dummy app for testing my app if it handles the transaction without debiting money from my bank account? Paytm has one but I am not using paytm

Answer (score 0):

The following version of [Google Pay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user) should have UPI integration.

If it isn't accessible to you, I wonder if it might be restricted to certain countries. Which country is your Play account associated with?